# Match all exact words in a query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-7

I want to create a query using the ElasticSearch Java API which only matches (1) complete words and (2) all of the words from the searchquery. Here is an example for that:

Text:

`hello wonderful world`

These should match:

```
hello
hello wonderful
hello world
wonderful world
hello wonderful world
wonderful
world
```

These shouldn't match:

1. `hell`
2. `hello fniefsgbsugbs`

I tried the following parameters for a match query but it still matches the two examples above.

This is the code to generate the query using the ElasticSearch 7.7.1 Java API:

```kotlin
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders
...

QueryBuilders.matchQuery(field, query)
            .autoGenerateSynonymsPhraseQuery(false)
            .fuzziness(0)
            .prefixLength(0)
            .fuzzyTranspositions(false)
            .operator(Operator.AND)
            .minimumShouldMatch("100%")
```

Which will generate this query:

```json
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "searchableText": {
              "query": "hell",
              "operator": "AND",
              "fuzziness": "0",
              "prefix_length": 0,
              "max_expansions": 50,
              "minimum_should_match": "100%",
              "fuzzy_transpositions": false,
              "lenient": false,
              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": false,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone help me to find a good solution for this?

**Edit:** Here are the settings and mappings (I removed everything which isn't relevant for `searchableText` to make it as minimal as possible):

```json
{
    "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "normalizer": {
          "lowercase_normalizer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "german_stemmer": {
            "type": "stemmer",
            "language": "light_german"
          },
          "ngram_filter": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "max_shingle_size": 4,
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "output_unigrams": false,
            "output_unigrams_if_no_shingles": false
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "german": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "german_synonyms",
              "german_stop",
              "german_keywords",
              "german_no_stemming",
              "german_stemmer"
            ]
          },
          "german_ngram": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "german_synonyms",
              "german_keywords",
              "german_no_stemming",
              "german_stemmer",
              "ngram_filter"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": "searchableText",
          "analyzer": "german"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": "searchableText",
          "analyzer": "german"
        },
        "userTags": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "copy_to": "searchableText",
          "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
        },
        "searchableText": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "german",
          "fields": {
            "ngram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "german_ngram"
            }
          }
        },
        "searches": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "copy_to": "searchableText",
          "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Edit 2:** These are the mentioned filters:

```json
"filter": {
    "german_stop": {
      "type": "stop",
      "stopwords": "_german_"
    },
    "german_stemmer": {
      "type": "stemmer",
      "language": "light_german"
    },
    "ngram_filter": {
      "type": "shingle",
      "max_shingle_size": 4,
      "min_shingle_size": 2,
      "output_unigrams": false,
      "output_unigrams_if_no_shingles": false
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add index mapping particularly for the field `searchableText` and also any associated setting to the field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added the settings. I hope that helps.

Comment: @Peter, I tried your mapping and sample doc and it works the way you want, pls see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried creating index with your setting and mapping, but as below filters were not provided, I got the error and created index after removing these filters.

```
"german_synonyms",
"german_stop",
"german_keywords",
"german_no_stemming",
```

After that I indexed, your sample doc `hello wonderful world` and used your search query but it works fine as your expected and didn't return a result for `hell` or `hello fniefsgbsugbs` As shown below

```
{
    "size": 100,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "searchableText": {
                            "query": "hello fniefsgbsugbs",
                            "operator": "AND",
                            "fuzziness": "0",
                            "prefix_length": 0,
                            "max_expansions": 50,
                            "minimum_should_match": "100%",
                            "fuzzy_transpositions": false,
                            "lenient": false,
                            "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": false,
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And it returns

```
"hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
```

Ans same is with `hell` , while it returns result with `hello`, `hello wonderful` and other terms which is expected to match.

**EDIT:** You are using [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) which is analyzed ie, it analyzes the search term, applies the same analyzer which is applied index time on the field, and matches the search time tokens to index time tokens.

**In order to properly debug these kinds of issues, please use the [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html#indices-analyze) and inspect your indexed document tokens and search terms tokens.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my problem is that I don't want `hell` to match with `hello`. Do you know a solution for that?

Comment: @Peter, `hell` is not matching `hello` , I tried again :), can you provide your missing fiters, I guess those filters are generating tokens different, that is causing issue

Comment: @Peter or can you simply try again with my setting and mapping, you can see its working according to your requirements.

Comment: I think you are correct that my settings are the cause why its not working. I added the filters as well to my question. Can you please have a look at them? Could it be the `ngram_filter` filter?

Comment: @Peter, I looked and your updated setting, but if you notice you are not using the `ngram_filter` in `german` analyzer and this `german` analyzer you are using on `searchableText`  while `german_ngram` analyzer which uses `ngram_filter` is used on its subfield called `ngram`, which you are not using in the query(atlleast query you provided its not included).

Comment: @Peter, please see edit part of my answer where I added more info.

Answer (score 0):

for fields indexed as "keywords" i often prefer QueryString Query DSL over Match Query.
for instance:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "my_field:('hello', 'wonderful', 'world')"
        }
    }
}
```

will match all those combinations you wrote should match, and not the ones you don't want. the relation of the terms in the parenthesis is like SQL "IN", so any one that appears in the field will match the document. plus, this format gives you great flexibility in creating complex searches. let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion but `hell` still matches for `hello` which is not what I want. Do you know any way to not let parts of a word match?